# LWR SPA - how to add additional JS modules for consume

Tags: lwr

LWR -> Lightning Web Runtime developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwr/guide/lwr-intro.html

I'll try to provide a clear project structure and questions. While learning LWR, I've started a new LWR project and chose a Single Page App for the project type

This gives a starting project structure like the following:

```
src
- modules / example
- - app
- - - app.css
- - - app.js
- - - app.html
lwr.config.json
package.json
```

My question is what is the correct way to include other npm packages or modules for consumption in my project? Do I need to add new module references to my lwr.config.json?

I've tried including some directly in my app.js but learned that is not the way with project type of module.

Thanks in advance for taking a look, I know LWR is still new so looking to learn where I can. I appreciate it!

Comment: What is LWR? It's helpful to define the full term before using the shortened version. Doubly so when it's something new (as you claim it is).

Comment: LWR -> Lightning Web Runtime https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwr/guide/lwr-intro.html

Answer (score 1):

There's a demo of this in [lwc-recipes-oss](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes-oss).

First, you just install d3:

```
npm install d3 --save
```

Then you can import it in your JS file:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
...
```

You can clone the repo and follow the instructions in the README.md file to see d3 in action, as well as seeing it in action in the [LWC OSS documentation](https://recipes.lwc.dev/#party).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Can this still be accomplished when the module is an inbuilt node module that needs a "requires" statement instead of the ES6 "import"?

Comment: @nickforce In LWC OSS, `import { LightningElement } from 'lwc'` is actually importing from an installed node module called `lwc`. This is done via webpack to build the components and babel to provide backwards compatibility for older browsers. As such, the example should work fine if you've installed a library that does something you need to do.

Comment: If I need to use a CommonJS method like 'requires' for example, should I be adding an installed node module to my LWR.Config.JSON?